# How to add a collaborator to a specific Github repository and have it appear on their profile aswell

Tags: github

I worked with another person on a project this summer and he uploaded all of the code to a repository on his Github and I am trying to figure out if there is an easy way to add the whole repository to my github also

Comment: if he adds you as a collaborator then your contributions will be linked automatically. Provided you use the same email address and username

Comment: We worked together on the code, but all of the final versions were on his computer so he uploaded all of them himself

Comment: you can ask him to commit again by adding you as a co-author, which can be done like this  Co-authored-by: name <name@example.com> https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors